# WebResource.axd failed to load when Azure site minimum TLS Version set into 1.2

Tags: c#, azure, tls1.2

Migrated C#.net 4.5 site to Azure and encountered "sys is not defined" error which apparently caused by webresources.axd fail to load.

We also notice that this problem didn't happen if we set the minimum TLS version in protocol settings into 1.0

tested it locally with IIS express works fine.

[Appinsight error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1GPn.png)

I tried adding the handler in web.config, ignore routing for *.axd, upgrade .net framework version to 4.6.2, forcing SSL protocol to 1.2 globally but none of these works nor make it reproduce able when running locally

Question: Has anybody encountered this problem ? Has anybody found any fix for this?

Thank you